# How do i get a Fragment to send onClickListener result back to the main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bluetooth

I've got a Main activity that when first started displays a fragment which displays a list view of Paired Bluetooth devices. I don't want to use a ListFragment as I want to display a TextView at the top.
I've created an onItemClickListener that sets strings with the MAC address and Name of the device selected. This is showing ok in the LOG
I want to send these Strings back to the Main activity for that then to open a different Fragment which uses these to connect to the Bluetooth device.

I've alredy got this working using all Activities, but want to change to Fragments.

My Main Activity is.

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
    private static String address = "No Device Selected";
    private static String itemName = "No Device Selected";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

the Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        class="com.ming.pondcontroller.AddressFragment"
        android:id="@+id/main_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Address Fragment

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class AddressFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "get address Activity";
    private BluetoothAdapter BA = null;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    LayoutInflater inflater2;
    ListView lv;
    String address;
    String itemName;
    String itemString;

    public AddressFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflater2 = inflater;
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_address, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        checkBTState();

        // get paired devices
        pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        // get a list of paired devices
        for(BluetoothDevice bt:pairedDevices){
            list.add(bt.getName()+"\n"+bt.getAddress());
        }
        // display the list in the list view
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(inflater2.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // onItemClick Listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,View view, int position, long l){
                // get the text of the item clicked from position
                itemString = (String)(lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
                // get last 17 characters for MAC address
                address = itemString.substring(itemString.length()-17);
                itemName = itemString.substring(0,itemString.length()-17);
                Log.d(TAG,address);

            }
        }); //end of onClickListener
    }

    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
        // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
        if(BA==null) {
            Log.d("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
        } else {
            if (BA.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And its layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorMainBack"
    tools:context="com.ming.pondcontroller.AddressFragment">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Select Device"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:background="@color/colorTextBack">
    </ListView> />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've looked at loads of examples of callbacks, listeners and interfaces but can't seem to find the right thing without using listFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment:

```
public static class AddressFragment extends Fragment {

    OnAddressListener mListener;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnAddressListener {
        public void onAddressChanged(String address);
    }

    // Use : mListener.onAddressChanged(address)

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnAddressListener ) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnAddressListener");
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnAddressListener{


    @Override
    public void onAddressChanged(String address){
           // Set your address
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface that your Activity will implement, then set that as a member variable in your Fragment in `onAttach()`:

Interface Class:

```
interface BluetoothItemSelected {
    void onBluetoothItemSelected(String itemName, String itemAddress);
}
```

MainActivity implementation:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BluetoothItemSelected {

    // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
    private static String address = "No Device Selected";
    private static String itemName = "No Device Selected";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothItemSelected(String itemName, String itemAddress) {
        // TODO do your work here
    }

    // your other Activity code...

}
```

Fragment implementation:

```
public class AddressFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "get address Activity";
    private BluetoothAdapter BA = null;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    LayoutInflater inflater2;
    ListView lv;
    String address;
    String itemName;
    String itemString;

    BluetoothItemListener btItemListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context activity) {
        if (activity instanceof BluetoothItemListener) {
            btItemListener = (BluetoothItemListener) activity;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        // remove the reference to your Activity
        btItemListener = null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        checkBTState();

        // get paired devices
        pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        // get a list of paired devices
        for(BluetoothDevice bt:pairedDevices){
            list.add(bt.getName()+"\n"+bt.getAddress());
        }
        // display the list in the list view
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(inflater2.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // onItemClick Listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,View view, int position, long l){
                // get the text of the item clicked from position
                itemString = (String)(lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
                // get last 17 characters for MAC address
                address = itemString.substring(itemString.length()-17);
                itemName = itemString.substring(0,itemString.length()-17);
                Log.d(TAG,address);
                // call your interface here
                if (btItemListener != null) {
                    btItemListener.onBluetoothItemSelected(itemName, address);
                }
            }
        }); //end of onClickListener
    }

    // your other Fragment code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do this in my code, I use `LocalBroadcastManager` to broadcast local messages with intents that are picked up by the activity using a `BroadcastReceiver`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

I am not sure if it is the *best* way, but it works nicely for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is in your Activity you implement a listener.  Then in your fragment you call that listener in the onClick

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        yourActivityListener = (IActivityListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement IActivityListener");
    }
}
```

in your onItemClicked method you can call it this way

```
yourActivityListener.onItemClicked();
```

this will be sent to your activity to know what item got clicked.